# C++ 2d array... lost on prototype and calling don't see this anywhere

Tags: c++, arrays, function, prototype

1. I need help with the prototype.
2. I need help with the caller.
3. I need help with the function header.

I don't know how much more detail this site wants me to add, but the code speaks for itself, I am having trouble with the top three items but for some reason the site wants more context?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fillArray(int salesSheet[][COLSIZE], int rowSize);
// I dont know how to create prototype for 2d array
int main()
{
    const int ROWSIZE = 5, COLSIZE = 6;
    int salesSheet[ROWSIZE][COLSIZE], a, rowSize;

    fillArray(a[][COLSIZE], int rowSize);
    // I don't know where I messed this up 
    // I messed up the caller too, help?
    return 0;
}
void fillArray(int salesSheet[][COLSIZE], int rowSize)
{
    int r, c;
    cout <<"Enter sales report for each quarter, for your branch." << endl;
    for (c = 0; c < COLSIZE; c++) 
    {
        for (r = 0; r < rowSize; r++)
            cout << "\nBranch " << c+1 << " quarterly sales figures:"
        cin >> salesSheet[r][c];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int ROWSIZE = 5, COLSIZE = 6;

void fillArray(int salesSheet[][COLSIZE]);

int main()
{
int salesSheet[ROWSIZE][COLSIZE];

fillArray(salesSheet);

return 0;
}
void fillArray(int salesSheet[][COLSIZE])
{
int r, c;
cout <<"Enter the sales report for each quarter, in you branches column."    
<<  endl;
for (c = 0; c < COLSIZE; c++) 
    {
    for (r = 0; r < ROWSIZE; r++)
        {
            cout << "\nBranch " << c+1 << " quarterly sales figures:" ;
            cin >> salesSheet[r][c];    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, tried it...before editing it and posting - forgot a semicolon before cin command 8x. Thanks for the help Alex, appreciate it man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
using namespace std;
const int ROWSIZE = 5, COLSIZE = 6;
void fillArray(int*** salesSheet, int rowSize, int colSize);

int main()
{
    int** salesSheet = (int**)malloc(COLSIZE*sizeof(int*));
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(ROWSIZE*COLSIZE*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < COLSIZE; i++)
      salesSheet[i] = arr+i;

    fillArray(&salesSheet, ROWSIZE, COLSIZE);
    free(salesSheet);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
void fillArray(int*** salesSheet, int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int r, c;
    cout <<"Enter sales report for each quarter, for your branch." << endl;
    for (c = 0; c < COLSIZE; c++) 
    {

        for (r = 0; r < rowSize; r++){
            cout << "\nBranch " << c+1 << " quarterly sales figures:";

            cin >> salesSheet[0][r][c];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, and it doesn't work. Tried playing around with several different coding changes...and nothing =/

Comment: Ok, I see 10 min please

Comment: Well, I have been playing with it and came up with this...and now I am stuck on the last line (cin).

Comment: It is another variant, with some other opportunities, happy that you've handled your one, but if I write 2d array, I will write it in this way. Good luck!